# exposing extension attributes when authenticating via azure AD - claims aware applications in Azure AD

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, azure-active-directory, claims-based-identity

So my org uses some in-house software that we developed a few years ago. We originally built it to be claims aware with ADFS, using WS-Fed. To work properly, the software needs 2 things, the user's group memberships, and the user's employee number (which we use as a key across the many different applications we use).

Since then, we've migrated to Azure AD (maintaining our on-premises AD servers, and syncing them periodically with Azure AD).

Now, I've gotten authentication working, and I've managed to expose the groups to the application by changing the application manifest to:

[image]

The group memberships use an azure AD key identifier, as opposed to exposing the text name of the group, but that's fine, I can figure out the mapping.

I've also borrowed a handy little debug page from a microsoft guide, such that I can see all the claims present for each user:

[image]

Question is, how do I edit the manifest such that I can see the 'employeeID' attribute. The other option is to show 'extensionattribute2'. We use some third party software that can see these attributes, so it must be possible.

Is doing this via the manifest the correct approach? Do I need to interface with Microsoft Graph to sort this out?

Edit:

So on some further research, I've found [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-application-objects), which makes me suspect that I need to use the Graph API to get at this information. Am I correct there?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Question is, how do I edit the manifest such that I can see the 'employeeID' attribute. The other option is to show 'extensionattribute2'. We use some third party software that can see these attributes, so it must be possible.

Based on my experience, it seems that we cann't do that with adding the content in the manifest.

I try to registry a Directory schema extension via Graph API and the added a custom claim to my users. If we can get the same result via modifying azure app manifest,the content of manifest should reflect the extension details which I have registered, and next time we can follow the changed parts to modify the manifest to register Directory schema extension and add customized claims.

However, after I compared the manifest before register extension and after register extension, there is no differences.

It seems that modifying the manifest of azure app is not working.

But you could use graph API to register Directory schema extension as customized claims, for more information please please refer to [Directory schema extensions | Graph API concepts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/Azure/Ad/Graph/howto/azure-ad-graph-api-directory-schema-extensions#example-scenario)